# A Python "catch all" method for undefined/unimplemented attributes in classes

Tags: python

I *love* Python's `@property` decorate system.  I love that you can run custom code when you call `aClassObect.attribute`.  Especially for validating data when you're setting an attribute.  However, one thing that I want, but I can't find, is a way to run custom code when trying to set an attribute that doesn't exist.  For example, say I've got the following class:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Now, if I have `myObj`, which is an instance of class `C`, and I call `myObject.x = 42`, it will run the appropriate setter, which is great for validating data.  But this doesn't stop someone from calling `myOjbect.b = 47`, and it will happily create a new attribute called `b`.  Is there some way to run special code when setting a new attribute?  I'd the ability to raise errors to say something like "error, this attribute doesn't exist".

Comment: I've got a class which serves as an API to a database.  Each instance represents an entry.  After modifying an object's attributes, which represent fields in the database, you call `object.save()` to update the DB.  I'd rather an error be raised rather than fields be silently dropped because they don't actually exist in the DB.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on [Elazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2289509/elazar)'s answer, you'll want to override the [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) magic method and do a check in it to see if the attribute already exists. If not, raise an exception. Here's what that could look like for your class:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if not hasattr(self, name): # would this create a new attribute?
        raise AttributeError("Creating new attributes is not allowed!")
    super(C, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

It's also possible to override `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` if you want to deal with requests for non-existent attributes, but for the specific issue you have described this is probably not necessary.

Note that the `__setattr__` method I show above won't entirely play nicely with your current property, due to the deleter. If you delete `myObj.x`, afterwards getter will raise an exception if you try to access `x` later. This means that `hasattr` will return `False` when checking if `x` is an existing attribute, and so my `__getattr__` won't let you recreate it. If you really need to be able to delete (and recreate) specific attributes, you'll need a more sophisticated `__setattr__` implementation (it could check in the class for a property with the desired name, rather than just relying on `hasattr`).

Comment: oh wait, I was so sure this would work, but there's a catch: This restriction applies everywhere, including in the constructor when I'm initializing values.  I just tried it, and it stops me with the `AttributeError` in the constructor.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @J-bob: Ah, yes. You have to explicitly call something like `super(C, self).__setattr__("_x", None)` anywhere you set an attribute if you want to bypass the check.

Comment: I found a good solution.  At the top of my file, I `import inspect`.  Then I replace your line, `if not hasattr(self, name):` with `if not hasattr(self, name) and inspect.stack()[1][3] != '__init__':`.  `inspect.stack` let's you examine the calling stack, so this code checks the name of the method that calls it.  If the calling method is `__init__`, it lets allows the attribute to be created.  Otherwise it raises the error.  I recommend modifying your answer to show this.

Answer (score 11):

override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`.